# Fast Fibonacci slows to a crawl over 1,000,000

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, recursion, fibonacci

I've written a pretty standard fibonacci function through fast doubling using an algorithm derived from the matrix exponentiation algorithm which should run in O(log(n)) time and calls, but stalls out at around over 1,000,000 - even when that should be just around 25 calls.

Code:

```
"""
O(log(n)) time fibonacci algorithm using fast doubling derived from the matrix
squaring algorithm for the same thing.
"""

def fibonacci(num):
    "O(log(n)) implementation of fibonacci using fast doubling."
    if num >= 0:
        return fib_helper(num)[0]

def fib_helper(num):
    "Helper function for fibonacci()."
    if num == 0:
        return (0, 1)
    elif num == 1:
        return (1, 1)
    else:
        f_k, f_k_1 = fib_helper(num // 2)
        f_k_even = f_k * (2 * f_k_1 - f_k)
        f_k_odd = f_k_1 * f_k_1 + f_k * f_k
        return (f_k_even, f_k_odd) if num % 2 == 0 else (f_k_odd, f_k_even +
                f_k_odd)
```

This code *should* only generate log(n) calls to fib_helper and one call to fibonacci. For numbers greater than 1,000,000 it just stalls out and doesn't return.

I've tried implementing a basic decorator to to count function calls which tells me that it is only running 32 calls for 2^32, but it still stalls out at the end.

Why is this slowing to a halt on large integers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try running you code like this

```
print "calculating fib(1000000)"
res = fib(1000000)
print "displaying the result..."
print res
```

The problem is that `fib(1000000)` is a quite large number (>10<sup>200000</sup>). Your computer can operate on these numbers quite quicky because everything is done in binary.

When you try to display the number, it needs to be converted to base 10. This can be very time consuming!

Converting to hex is much easier. The bits just need to be grouped into fours, so

```
print hex(res)
```

will start spitting stuff out quite quickly

Comment: Try using `decimal.Decimal` and set the decimal precision "very large".  Then the output conversion time will become trivial (linear in the number of decimal digits) - CPython binary->decimal conversion time is quadratic in the number of bits.

Comment: If the number gets larger, even the calculating part is too slow to run. On my computer, fib(10,000,000) takes forever to run.

Comment: @Satoru.Logic, it takes less than 100ms for `fib(1000000)` on this computer

Comment: @Satoru.Logic , even printing `fib(1000000)` only takes 1s on my computer, I think memory usage is the bottleneck here.

Comment: @gnibbler On my machine it takes a little over 100ms, and running calling `str` with the result is more than 9 times slower.

Comment: I think maybe we should ignore `print` and `string conversion` in this case and focus on the algorithm. Yes, 10^6 works fine, but try 10^7, even calling `fib` is too slow. Maybe the last step takes too much time to run, we are calculating with numbers with several hundred thousand digits.

Comment: @Satoru.Logic When I called with 10^7, it finished in 3 seconds.

Comment: @TimPeters I tried `from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 30000000000
print Decimal(res)` It doesnt work. I use CPython only.

Comment: Right on the mark with the hex() comment. Now it will print 10**7 in just a second or two (1.73 million digits in hex!!). 10**8 still stalls, however. Also memory usage is not a problem on my machine, it says this takes only about 32 mb even while running 10**8.

Comment: @thefourtheye, the *arithmetic* has to be done using decimal, not just the output.  It requires changing the code.  Helps a *whole* lot to be using Python 3 too, where `decimal` is coded in C.  Setting precision to 3 billion may be a problem too - depends on the platform.  You don't need precision anywhere near that high for the millionth (or even the billionth) Fibonacci number - `fibonacci(n)` is approximately equal to `1.618**n`.

Comment: Nth fibonacci number has roughly N/5 digits.  Python 2's long and Python 3's int should able to handle arithmetic of numbers with ~200,000 digits without a problem.

Comment: @DmitryRubanovich, yes that's what my answer says. Converting the 200000 digits to base 10 for display is the intensive slow part.

Comment: @John La Rooy, I don't think the conversion is as slow as printing of the result.  You can compute the value F, and the compare the times of doing str(F), hex(F), print(F).  And I would bet that print would turn out to be much, much slower.  I was doing len(str(F)) before to get a sense of how large it was (before figuring out that it would be around N/5) and then realized that log(F)/log(10) would be much faster than len(str(F)).

Comment: @DmitryRubanovich, Why don't you try it yourself? `str(F)` will take most of the time that `print(F)` takes. Break the print into 2 steps so see the difference between the string conversion and printing the result: time `f=str(F)` and `print(f)` separately.

Comment: @John La Rooy, I did and you are absolutely right. For 1000,000th fib number str() took about a second, while print() took only .0004s. hex() was even more surprising because it took less than print() (only .00032s). Although it did take longer than printing to /dev/null (.00018s).

Answer (score 3):

Just for interest, since my `decimal` comments were apparently inscrutable ;--), here's the code:

```
import decimal
from decimal import Decimal as D
DO = D(0)
D1 = D(1)

def fibonacci(num):
    from math import log10
    if num >= 0:
        ndigits = int(log10(1.62) * num + 100)
        decimal.getcontext().prec = ndigits
        decimal.getcontext().Emax = ndigits
        return fib_helper(num)[0]

def fib_helper(num):
    if num == 0:
        return (D0, D1)
    elif num == 1:
        return (D1, D1)
```

and the rest of `fib_helper()` is unchanged (see the original message).  In Python 3, `decimal` is implemented in C, and computation time is comparable to using native (binary) integers.  But the *point* is the time for output conversion to a decimal string:  instead of being a huge bottleneck, it becomes a trivial part of the runtime.

For example, `fibonacci(100000000)` (a hundred million) takes about 30 seconds on this box, but after that:

```
>>> from time import clock as now # on this box, `clock()` is wall-clock time
>>> if 1:
...    t = now()
...    print(len(str(x)))
...    print(now()-t)
...
20898764
0.10466078789343337
```

So a tenth of a second to produce the string of 20+ million decimal digits.  For argument one billion, about 0.9 seconds to produce the 208,987,640-digit decimal string:  clearly linear in the number of decimal digits.

Note: `decimal` is really *aiming* at decimal floating- and fixed-point calculations.  While it can be used fine for high precision integer calculations, you have to specify the number of digits you'll need, and the maximum exponent, in advance.  It has no "unbounded" mode.  The code above uses that `fibonacci(n)` is approximately equal to `1.618**n`.